# how does this css footer stay at the bottom

Tags: css, footer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you get the footer to stay at the bottom of a Web page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page)

how does this site keep the footer at the bottom when the content is short?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42294/how-do-you-get-the-footer-to-stay-at-the-bottom-of-a-web-page

Comment: use Firebug to know how.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sticky footer solution like http://ryanfait.com/sticky-footer/ or http://www.cssstickyfooter.com/

Answer (score 0):

```
 #footer{
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
 }
```

Comment: What happens when the text grows beyond the bottom of the browser window :P then you have a footer thats too far up.

Comment: lol, good point. anyway to have this style rule conditionally applied without js?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, warn before putting a man's butt on the screen. Second, use firebug. Third, its called position: absolute.